# Why does GridView inside a Repeater (or other similar controls) has the event PageIndexChanging as NOT IMPLEMENTED

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding, webforms, repeater

Simply I want to know WHY!

Is it the DataSource Type of the GridView? or the Repeater inner implementation?

The error text:

`The GridView 'grdArticles' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled.`

Here's the Markup code, I think it's familiar enough for everyone.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCategories" DataSourceID="ldsCategories" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>


        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdArticles" AllowPaging="true" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="id" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSource='<%# Eval("Articles") %>'>
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false" ItemStyle-Width="100%" FooterStyle-Width="100%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="article-menu-item">
                        <h1>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTitle" CssClass="article-menu-title" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("title") %>' 
                                NavigateUrl='<%# Vars.ArticleUrl + "?action=view&id=" + Eval("id") %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
                        </h1>

                        <!-- Date -->
                        <div class="article-menu-date">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("date") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Meta Content -->
                        <div class="article-menu-meta">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("meta") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="article-menu-delete">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" TargetID='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                        </div>
                        <!-- Line -->
                        <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc"></div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <p>No items to view!</p>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>

        <br />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

EDIT:

If I implement the OnPageIndexChanging event using the code (And modified the aspx gridview markup to handle the event):

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdArticles" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdArticles_PageIndexChanging" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="id" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSource='<%# Eval("Articles") %>'>
```

cs:

```
protected void grdArticles_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{   
    GridView grd = sender as GridView;

    grd.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grd.DataBind();

}
```

Another exception thrown:

`Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.`

### Edit #2:

After following Mr @Garrison solution, and handling the Repeater itemDataBound event using the code:

```
protected void rptCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    GridView grd = e.Item.FindControl("grdArticles") as GridView;

    if (grd != null)
    {
        DatabaseDataClassesDataContext dc = new DatabaseDataClassesDataContext();
        grd.DataSource = dc.Articles.Where(a => a.category_id == (e.Item.DataItem as Category).id);
        grd.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Got another problem: No exceptions thrown, but when navigating to another page, the GridView shows NO ROWS!!

I really think that there is an issue in the repeater core implementation!

Comment: Is is very simple actually. You have enabled paging (`AllowPaging="True")` on the GridView but are not handling the `PageIndexChanging ` event in the code-behind.

Comment: But this is what I actually do, and that's not working!

Comment: Nowhere in the code you included in your question shows that you are handling the `PageIndexChanging` event. I suggest you follow the answer from  @GarrisonNeely

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Remove Paging: Set `AllowPaging="false"` in your GridView.
- Implement Paging: Set `OnPageIndexChanging="grdArticles_PageIndexChanging"`

Create a method in your code behind that looks like this:

```
protected void grdArticles_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdArticles.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grdArticles.DataBind();
}
```

Now that we're past the first issue, let's tackle the second one.  You need to handle your `Repeater`'s `ItemDataBound` event.  Inside there, first find your GridView with the following code:

`var grdArticles = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("grdArticles");`

Now you have access to the GridView, but you've got to find the set of Articles you want to data bind to the GridView.  I don't know how you're retrieving your data, so I leave that portion up to you, but once you find your list of articles to bind, use the following code:

```
grdArticles.DataSource = relevantArticles; // relevantArticles is a stand-in variable name, because I don't know how you're going to do it
grdArticles.DataBind();
```

Comment: But by setting AllowPaging to false, the Pager will no longer visible!

Comment: You are missing `OnPageIndexChanging="grdArticles_PageIndexChanging"` in your GridView's declaration ASPX.

Comment: No I'm not, I really added it :(

Comment: Update your post with the ASPX from your page and let's verify.

Comment: Mr @Garrison I've edited the post, but note that I'm setting AllowPaging to True, because setting it to false will no longer let me select pages

Comment: Go back and read my comments.  You are missing me completely.  You have created the method in the code-behind, yes.  But the GridView has to be told where to look in the code-behind for your method.  That's why you need to add `OnPageIndexChanging="grdArticles_PageIndexChanging"` in your GridView's ASPX markup.  It can go right after your `AllowPaging` setting.

Comment: Mr @Garrison, I'm sorry it seems you are reading the first code snippet, I want you to read the second one, in the bottom of the post, I've added the property OnPageIndexChanging="grdArticles_PageIndexChanging" and got the new exception I've written in the last line of the post, I'm sorry if I make some headache :(

Comment: I'm betting that's because you set the DataSource to that Eval of Articles.  Don't think that'll work.  Handle the Repeater's ItemDataBound event, and then...I'll just update my answer.

Comment: Mr @Garrison, Could you see Edit #2 ?

Comment: Looks like in your paging implementation you need to bind in a similar way as you do with the itemdatabound.  Will not be trivial since you need to get the Category ID, which isn't easily available in the paging.  A quick thought is storing the result of `dc.Articles.Where(a => a.category_id == (e.Item.DataItem as Category).id);` in `ViewState` so that you can retrieve it on the paging easily.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out -with the help of others answers- that's the problem is with the DataSource type, which is -in my example- the `Eval("Items")`, I don't know really what's the type of it, but it's not supporting auto paging.

So, one way to step out of it *-without rewriting paging logic and writing lots of code and get some mess with Sessions and querying-* is to handle the ItemDataBound of the container of the GridView, I mean the Repeater or DataList, or you can handle the OnPreRender of the GridView and create the DataSource that supports the auto paging like `LinqDataSource`.

You may also need to handle the `PageIndexChanging` of the GridView like what @Garrison told us:

```
protected void grdArticles_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdArticles.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grdArticles.DataBind();
}
```

After that I got everything work :)